# Making DropCreateDatabaseAlways work with custom DbMigrationsConfiguration

Tags: entity-framework-6

Using ef6 code first and mysql I got the following exception:

`Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes.`

To fix it I created custom `HistoryContext` and shortened `ContextKey` length.
And to use `MyHistoryContext` I created Configuration class inherited from `DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>`.

After creation of Configuration class DropCreateDatabaseAlways db initializer stopped to work throwing:

```
The DropCreateDatabaseAlways initializer did not drop or create the database backing context 'MyContext' because Migrations are enabled for the context.
```

A̶n̶d̶ ̶s̶e̶t̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶A̶u̶t̶o̶m̶a̶t̶i̶c̶M̶i̶g̶r̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶E̶n̶a̶b̶l̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶ ̶d̶i̶d̶n̶t̶ ̶h̶e̶l̶p̶. (I've understood that its unrelated.)

**Edit.**
I want to reformulate the problem: creating `Configuration` class inherited from `DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>` (to use custom `HistoryContext` wich solves `Specified key was too long` problem in mysql) made ef think that I've enabled migrations via `Enable-Migrations` command and `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` stopped to work (but this is intended behaviour as far as I understand). But afterall this is not a big problem because I can create custom initializer with

```
context.Database.Create();
context.Database.Drop();
```

So, did I understand it correct?

Custom HistoryContext:

```
public class MyDbHistoryContext : HistoryContext
{
    public MyDbHistoryContext(DbConnection existingConnection, string defaultSchema)
        : base(existingConnection, defaultSchema) 
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>()
            .Property(x => x.ContextKey)
            .HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}
```

Comment: care to share your custom `HistoryContext` class?